# How to handle Solutions, Projects and their contents in a VisualStudio extension

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

**In short:**
I'm new to VisualStudio Extensibility and my goal is to create an extension with a ToolWindow (which already works) showing different views for each context of a VisualStudio solution, i. e. a view for the solution, a view for a project etc.. The window should be opened by clicking on a context menu entry in the context menus of the Solution Explorer, Class View, Object Browser and (ideally) any other window showing contents like projects, namespaces, classes etc..

After searching I found a lot of information, but for some points I couldn't find very helpful information. How do I ...

- ... create a context menu item for the VisualStudio views?
- ... get the currently open solution as an instance in code?
- ... get the projects of the solution and their contens as instances in code?
- ... add/remove items to/from a solution/project/class/... in code?
- ... react to selection changes in the Solution Explorer?

**What I've done, so far:**
I read the docs for [Starting to Develop Visual Studio Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions) and downloaded the [VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples). Especially the WPF_Toolwindow example was interesting for my purposes, so I built and ran it, which was successful, so far. Another interesting sample would have been the WPFDesigner_XML, but it always throws a NullReferenceException, so I decided to stick with the former ToolWindow, which is completely fine, for now.

Furtermore, I tried to understand the example by having a close look at each file in the project, running it in the debugger and analyzing what happened. I'm confident I understood it, but am also open for corrections of my possibly misguided thoughts following.

Now, I have created a new project, based on the WPF_Toolwindow sample, renamed and adapted to my needs (basically, I created new GUIDs, renamed the namespaces and removed things I won't use). This extension still works in the debugger. I even uninstalled everything from the experimental instance and debugged the extension from scratch.

**What I try to achieve:**

- Have the ToolWindow load a specific view/viewmodel, when the selection changes in the Solution Explorer (or any other VisualStudio view). Alternatively, there should be a context menu item for every node's context menu in the Solution Explorer tree (or any other VisualStudio view).
- Get the currently open solution, the containing projects and basically everything from the Solution Explorer's content as instances processable in my viewmodel. I need to properly add/remove

  - classes/structs/enums to/from

    1. a folder in a project
    2. a namespace
  - properties/fields to/from a class/struct
- Generate code based on information of the solution and add the file properly to a project.

Does anyone know of examples for something like this or can anyone give me some hints, where I can find further information? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first problem, do you mean add context menu on project item dynamically. the second problem, please try to use Roslyn to get related classes from solution.

Comment: The third problem, do you mean generate a code file and add the file to project?

Comment: (1) The items already have a context menu and I want to add a new command to this menu. (2) Thanks for the Roslyn hint, I will have a look. (3) Yes, basically adding a file to a project without manually manipulating the project file would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) The items already have a context menu and I want to add a new command to this menu.

if you want to add a sub menu to the context menu, the following link provide a complete sample
[image]

https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/CommandSubmenu

> (3) Yes, basically adding a file to a project without manually manipulating the project file would be nice.

You can add the file to project via Project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile, and the following provide a sample for your reference.

https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2014/MZ2014009.aspx

Update:

> I select a project and a similar event is fired. Are there such events I can subscribe to?

You could use IVsMonitorSelection to implement. here is the code which retrieve related project path for your reference.

```
IntPtr hierarchyPointer, selectionContainerPointer;
            Object selectedObject = null;
            IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect;
            uint projectItemId;

            IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection =
                    (IVsMonitorSelection)Package.GetGlobalService(
                    typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection));

            monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPointer,
                                                 out projectItemId,
                                                 out multiItemSelect,
                                                 out selectionContainerPointer);

            IVsHierarchy selectedHierarchy = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(
                                                 hierarchyPointer,
                                                 typeof(IVsHierarchy)) as IVsHierarchy;

            if (selectedHierarchy != null)
            {
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(selectedHierarchy.GetProperty(
                                                  projectItemId,
                                                  (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject,
                                                  out selectedObject));
            }

            Project selectedProject = selectedObject as Project;

            string projectPath = selectedProject.FullName;
```

For more information about the usage, please refer to:

https://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007024.aspx

Comment: Your comment in the original question had me reading more about Roslyn, which seems to be exactly what I want. The VSX-Samples included my context menu needs - thanks for that hint, must have confused them with the VSSDK-Samples. The MZ-Tools look interesting, but I don't want to buy something during learning and Roslyn seems to fit my needs already well enough. If you could add some information about how to react to selection changes in the solution explorer, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your helpful answer :)

Comment: >If you could add some information about how to react to selection changes in the solution explorer, do you mean the context menu in solution explorer, if so, the link I provide is open source, you can download it free. if not, could you please describe it in detailed.

Comment: No, the context menu has been another part of the question. I mean: I click on the current solution in the solution explorer, then the solution is selected and an event like SolutionNodeSelected is fired. Or, I select a project and a similar event is fired. Are there such events I can subscribe to? The Toolwindow sample used a selection tracker for updating the contents of the properties window. Maybe I need to use something similar, but I couldn't figure it out, yet.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks good. Currently, I'm not able to try it, because I messed up my solution (I'll post a separate question, if I don't solve it myself). Anyway, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: My solution is working again and I continued with the context menus. I created commands and could fire them by clicking on the corresponding context menu item, but in the `MenuItemCallback` method of the command I don't have any information about the node on which the context menu has been opened. I have the `OleMenuItem` in the `sender` parameter and getting an `OleCommandService`, I see a `ParentTarget` property there, which is always `null`. How do I get a `Solution` or `Project` or `Document` or similar object in the callback method?